# Speechcontrol Java?

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I will build an speech control apllication like "Jarvis" from Ironman movie.
I found at the internet many examples for homecontrolling systems but not how they realized.

My wish is an application in Java to support cross platforming but i cant find any good speech to text api's or examples how to use it.

At google i found Sphinx-4, but the last release are from 2009 and im not sure that is the best choice.

Maybe you can help me.

Comment: I don't think there is any human language that changed so drastically in 4 years that Sphinx-4 won't be able to recognize it (if it could before). Perhaps it uses some deprecated/removed APIs, but it shouldn't be that hard to replace/work around that (unless they use compiled binaries from which you don't have the source).

Comment: Not much has changed since then. There is nothing better for Java.

Comment: @Dariusz Well, with Java 7 released and such I didn't want to unnecessarily frustrate the OP and thus warn him it was possible Sphinx-4 used outdated/deprecated stuff, I didn't mean to say that that is likely.

Comment: @11684 my answer is unrelated to yours. I'm familiar with the subject, I've got my masters degree working with Sphinx. Java Speech API remains unchanged since... 2005? Or even earlier.

Comment: Sorry, I thought your comment was meant as an addition to my comment. @Dariusz

Comment: this arguments are so true, i will build the Application with sphinx.